# Loading regular expression patterns from external source?

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of regular expression patterns defined for automated processing of text. Due to the design of the program, it's better to have these patterns separate in a text file, namely a JSON file. The pattern in Python is of `r''` type, but all I can provide is a string. I'd like to retain functionalities such as grouping. I'd like to have features such as entities (`[A-z]`), so I'm not talking about escaping everything.

I'm using Python 3.4. How do I properly load these patterns into the `re` module? And what kind of escaping problem should I watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want but have a look at this.:

If you have a file called input.txt containing `\d+`

Then you can use it this way:

```
import re
f=open("input.txt","r")
x="asasd3243sdfdsf23234sdsdf"
print re.findall(r""+f.readline(),x)
```

Output:`['3243', '23234']`

When you use `r` mode you need not escape anything.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, is there any escaping issue I should watch out for?

Comment: @HeShiming if the regex in file is legitimate,this should work for all cases.

Comment: What's the `r""+` bit for?

Comment: @Rawing it might not actaully be needed here ..but i have put it in case OP wants to add some string like `r".*"+f.readline()` or simething like that

Answer (score 1):

The r'' thing in Python is not a different type than simple ''. The r'' syntax simply creates a string that looks exactly like the one you typed, so the \n sequence stays as \n, and isn't turned into a new line (same thing happens to other special characters). This little r simply escapes everything you type.

Check it yourself with this two simple lines in the console:

```
print('test \n test')
print(r'test \n test')
print(type(r''))
print(type(''))
```

Now, while you read lines from JSON file, the escaping is done for you. I don't know how will you create the JSON file, but you should take a look at the json module, and the [load](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.load) method, that will allow you to read a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the strings. However this is escaping *everything* and you might want some special chars. I'd just use the strings and be careful about placing `\` in the right places.

BTW: If you have many regular expressions, matching might get slow. You might want to consider some alternatives such [esmre](https://code.google.com/p/esmre/).

Comment: But I'm not looking for escaping everything kind of solution. I need those patterns to work.

Comment: Then use `\\` whenever you don't want special meaning :)